# How do I transfer my previous weight painting I did in the skeleton to the rigify controlers

Tags: mesh, rigging, rigify

I spent the last 2 days weight painting a skeleton and when I use rigify to generate controls for my rig the only real way to rig the whole thing together is to use automatic weights.

Is there any way I can transfer my skeleton weights into the control weights?

Answer (score 2):

Select the mesh, shift select the armature and press Ctrl P using the option "Armature Deform".

Then rename the vertex groups of the mesh using exactly the names of the Rigify deforming bones (thoose which have the "DEF" suffix, all of them can be found into the third from the last bone layer).

Answer (score 0):

To clear out a few possible confusions or approximate formulations:

### Can rigify generate controllers on your rig?

Rigify doesn't generate "*controls for [your] rig*". It generates a whole rig, with its own deform rig, mechanics controllers and whatnot. It generates that full feature rig from a "metarig", provided by Rigify, which you can customize using Rigify's modules system. But it can only work with its own system.
It is not meant to work on top of another pre-existing rig out of the box. That would usually require a third party tool, like retargeting system that can make Rigify control that rig.

More about Rigify on [Rigify — Blender Manual](https://docs.blender.org/manual/en/2.81/addons/rigging/rigify.html)

### Can weights be transferred across rigs?

Yes and no.

Weights are just vertex groups, the way Blender knows which vertex group to use to bing mesh parts to bones is with these two steps:

1. Have an Armature Deform modifier on the mesh object(s), which allows to tell which armature object deforms the mesh and using which method (weights or envelope)
2. If using weights: each "deform" bone of the armature will seek a vertex group of the same name to know what vertices it can influence.

This means, you doń't "transfer" weights across rigs: weights are data on the mesh object. You can reuse the same weights with any rig you want. However, as the names of the bones and vertex group need to mach, it usually means that weights made for one rig aren't necessarily "functional" for another rig: names can be different (which can be an easy fix), and the weights may be doing the wrong deformations for a different rig (articulations can be placed differently, some rigs have more limbs or even sub-limbs that others don't have).

So, unless your two rigs were made the same on the deformation level, using the same weights will probably not give a good result. But it might still save some time, you can work from something already existing instead of from scratch.

And if your two rigs match, there's likely no extra work to do.

If you never assigned a rig to your mesh, all you have to is to select all your mesh objects in object mode, then <kbd>⇧ Shift</kbd> select the armature, and press <kbd>⎈ Ctrl</kbd><kbd>P</kbd> > Armature Deform.

If you have the same rigs with just different names in your deformation bones, you can simply rename either bones or vertex groups accordingly.

If you already parented your mesh objects to an armature before, you should probably delete any Armature Deform Modifiers first.

If your situation is different from any of these, or you need more details, please [edit] your post to detail more precisely your situation, consider uploading screenshots or even your file.